# How do I add a class to a select in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is what i've been trying:

```
<%= select (:filter, :min_sale_price, item.buy_prices.map {|p| [Money.new(p, :gbp).format(:no_cents), p / 100]}, selected: params[:filter] && params[:filter][:min_sale_price], include_blank: 'No minimum', :class => "form-control") %><br />
```

I've also tried using:

```
, class: "form-control")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of the method you're calling is as follows:

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

Without wrapping any of the parts of your hash of various options, they will all be assumed to be a single hash, and will be passed as `options` to the 4th parameter of that method.

To avoid this, you should group the first (or both) sets of options within curly braces to explicitly pass the intended hash to the correct parameter of the method:

```
<%= select(:filter, :min_sale_price, item.buy_prices.map {|p| [Money.new(p, :gbp).format(:no_cents), p / 100]}, {selected: params[:filter] && params[:filter][:min_sale_price], include_blank: 'No minimum'}, :class => "form-control") %><br />
```

UPDATE:

I noticed you have a space before the parentheses after your call to `select`. You either need to drop the parentheses (keeping the space) or drop the space. You can't have a space and the parentheses.

Comment: I've tried both options and still getting errors not 100% sure why.

Comment: What error are you getting? (see my update above before you reply)

Comment: Weird now it works! sorry for the confusion, thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to [group the Rails options from the HTML options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select).

```
<%= select (:filter, :min_sale_price, item.buy_prices.map {|p| [Money.new(p, :gbp).format(:no_cents), p / 100]}, {selected: params[:filter] && params[:filter][:min_sale_price], include_blank: 'No minimum'}, {:class => "form-control"}) %><br />
```